# Why is my Where clause being ignored in this LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq, class, generics

The provided Linq statement is intended to bring back data of only the parents which have children that have read the book "Huck.........". For some reason though, my query seems to be ignoring the `Where` clause as I am returning the entire data set `Parents` every time. Where is this query failing? Why doesn't the `Where` seem to affect the results?

```
List<Parent> we = Parents.Select(par => new Parent
{
    ParentID = par.ParentID,
    Children = parents.SelectMany(parData => parData.Children).ToList().Where(child => new Child
    {
        ChildID = child.ChildID,
        Books = child.Books
    }.Books.Contains("Huck........")).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

### Classes

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent() { }

    public int ParentID { get { return _parentID; } set { _parentID = value; } }
    public List<Child> Children { get { return _child; } set { _child = value; } }
}
public class Child
{
    private int _childID;
    private List<string> _targets;

    public Child() { }

    public int ChildID { get { return _childID; } set { _childID = value; } }
    public List<string> Books { get { return _books; } set { _books = value; } }
}
```

### Table

```
 Parent ID |     Parent      | Child ID |     Child     |     Books 
1          | John            | 4        | Suzy          | Grapes of...
1          | John            | 4        | Suzy          | Huck........
1          | John            | 5        | James         | The adven...
2          | Sally           | 4        | Suzy          | Grapes of...
2          | Sally           | 4        | Suzy          | Huck........
2          | Sally           | 5        | James         | The adven...
3          | Fred            | 6        | Jane          | Purple......
```

Comment: I wonder what `Convert.ToInt32("Huck........")` converts to when translated to SQL. It just doesn't make sense. You're trying to turn a string into a number. Whaaa?

Comment: Not sure if serious... o.o

Comment: @spender Sorry, mistyping. No more conversion.

Comment: @Volearix But that wouldn't compile. Books is a List of ints, not strings...

Comment: @Volearix The edit has turned this from a question that kind-of made sense into a useless question with code that won't compile.

Comment: @J.Steen What are you talking about? `Books` is obviously a list of strings?

Comment: @Volearix From your code: `public List<int> Books`

Answer (score 3):

So...

```
.Where(child => new Child
{
    ChildID = child.ChildID,
    Books = child.Books
}.Books.Contains(Convert.ToInt32("Huck........"))
```

can be shortened to

```
.Where(child => child.Books.Contains(Convert.ToInt32("Huck........"))
```

but calling `Convert.ToInt32("Huck........")` isn't going to hand you the Id of a book with the title `"Huck........"`. It's going to convert the string to a number with somewhat useless results.

Comment: This still results in ALL results, not just the ones with Book "Huck.....". Exactly what I started with, only shorter.

Comment: Yes. I haven't changed anything in my code, just tried to point out the redundancy of creating a new `Child` just to access its `Books` collection. You're fundamentally misunderstanding how to perform the query on the `Books` collection. All it contains is a list of `int`. I assume this corresponds the the `id`s of `Book` rows in the DB. You'll need to figure out a way of bringing in the actual `Book` data into your query and querying the title of the `Book`.

Comment: @Volearix Post your ACTUAL code, not something you tried to retype full of error, Convert.ToInt32("Huck....") Would just give you an exception because you can't convert a non number string to an int, it just makes no sense, what people are trying to tell you is that you don't have a small error somewhere we can fix, both all of your code AND all of the logic you seem to have in your head around it makes no sense. So post your ACTUAL code (after testing that it compiles and run BEFORE posting it) and THEN post clearly what you are trying to achieve (without trying to guess what "does not work")